# Desktop Environment of kali linux

Tags: linux, gnome, kali-linux, desktop, cinnamon

Whats the desktop environment in kali linux 2.0 (sana) I am to able understand because they have some mixture of gnome + cinnamon and tell me  how can i do this with my fresh debian installation

Answer (score 0):

Kali Linux 2.0 default desktop environment is GNOME3 and Xfce.